How to Run a Github Workflows Job after an optional Job (but also needs mandatory jobs to be successful)
I have an Actions workflow file with several jobs configured. However, I am stuck with the following situation.
I have jobs configured in the following order:
job-1:
  name: first-job
  .
  .

job-2:
  name: second-job
  needs: [first-job]
  .
  .

job-3:
  name: optional-third-job
  if: <condition - executed only when true>
  needs: [first-job, second-job]
  .
  .

job-4:
  name: fourth-job
  needs: [first-job, second-job, optional-third-job]
  . 
  .


In this code above, I want the jobs to be executed sequentially and the job-3 optionally runs based on a condition after job-1 and job-2.
But, I want the job-4 to only run after job-3 (i.e.,  if job-3 has satisfied the condition); else, I want the job-4 to continue after job-2 (skipping job-3).
How do I achieve this?
I have tried adding
job-4:
  name: fourth-job
  needs: [first-job, second-job, optional-third-job]
  If: ${{ always() }}
  . 
  .


but I worry that adding always() will also skip the mandatory job-1 and job-2.

This should be sufficient:
name: Skip

on:
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  job-1:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-2:
    needs: job-1
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-3:
    if: false
    needs: job-2
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: exit 0

  job-4:
    needs: job-3
    if: always()
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: exit 0

NOTE: always() does not interfere with evaluation sequence specified by 'needs:'. job-4 will wait for decision from job-3. However, it will run even if job-2 fails. If this is undesirable, then
  job-4:
    needs: [job-2, job-3]
    if: always() && needs.job-2.result == 'success'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - run: exit 0

NOTYE: always() counteracts default logic that a job is skipped if a job it needs is skipped.
